# Not able to read input from client program

Tags: python, sockets, server, network-programming, client-server

I am trying to write Client-server code. I have added a menu in client code. and depending on input from a client I tried to add cases in the server code. I am able to send the client selected choice to server code, but not able to select a case from the received data.  Here is my code.

**server.py**

```
import socket

import sys

import os

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print (' socket created s1')    

serveraddress = ('localhost' , 2000)

print ('starting server on', serveraddress)

s1.bind(serveraddress)

s1.listen(3)

while True:

    print('waiting for connection')

    connection, clientaddress = s1.accept()

    print ('connecting with', clientaddress)

    command = connection.recv(1000)

    print (command)

    if command == '1':

        print('entered into 1st if')

        try:

            filename = connection.recv(1000)

            with open(filename, 'rb') as filetosend:

                for data in filetosend:

                    connection.sendall(data)

        finally:

            connection.close()

    if command == '2':

        print('entered into 2st if')

        filelist = os.listdir('C:\Rahul')

        connection.sendall(filelist)

    if command == '3':

        print('entered into 3st if')

        s1.close()

        break
```

**Client.py**

```
import sys

import os

import socket

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serveraddress = ('localhost' , 2000)

print ('connecting to server on'), serveraddress

s1.connect(serveraddress)

try:

    a = input('Enter you choice: \n 1-Get file \n 2-Get List \n 3-quit \n')

    while True:

        if a == 1:

            s1.send('1')

            b = input('enter file name: ')

            s1.send(b)

            downloadDir = r'C:\Users\rahul\Desktop'

            with open(os.path.join(downloadDir, b), 'wb') as filetowrite:

                while True:

                    data = s1.recv(1000)

                    if not data:

                        break

                    filetowrite.write(data)

                filetowrite.close()

            s1.close()

        elif a == 2:

            s1.send('2')

            #s1.sendall(' send all files list ')

            filelist = s1.recv(1000)

            print (filelist)

        elif a == 3:

            x = False

            print('closing connection')

            s1.close()      

finally:
    s1.close
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding except block too in client script, your code will work after that.
And I will suggest you to use raw_input for input purposes in sockets, and format the data type at input to avoid any error in program.

`import sys, os, socket
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serveraddress = ('localhost' , 2000)
print ('connecting to server on'), serveraddress
s1.connect(serveraddress)
try:
    a = int(raw_input('Enter you choice: \n 1-Get file \n 2-Get List \n 3-quit \n'))
    while True:
        if a == 1:
            s1.send('1')
            b = str(raw_input('enter file name: '))
            s1.send(b)
            # downloadDir = '\\root\\'
            # with open(os.path.join(downloadDir, b), 'wb') as filetowrite:
            #     while True:
            #         data = s1.recv(1000)
            #         if not data:
            #             break
            #         filetowrite.write(data)
            #     filetowrite.close()
            print "It worked till here."
            s1.close()
        elif a == 2:
            # s1.send('2')
            # #s1.sendall(' send all files list ')
            # filelist = s1.recv(1000)
            # print (filelist)
            print "It also worked till here."
        elif a == 3:
            x = False
            print "Closing Connection"
            s1.close()
except:
    print 'It Gave an Error'`

This worked fine.

Comment: Thank you Vipin for your help. That solved my problem. I still got some errors though. I'll work on that.

Comment: Glad it helped ^_^

Comment: But I still getting an error in server code while reading the input sent from the client for case selection.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do with this script ?

Comment: well, I have added a menu, like if in client he gives 1 as input after that he should give the filename and download it. If a client gives 2, he should get a list of available files in the server directory, and then a client can provide a file name and download it. And if provides 3, it should disconnect program.

Comment: But my server program is not able to interpret the commands i.e. choices given by client program and select the according case in server code.

Comment: Actually the problem with your script is that you are using wrong functions to perform your operation, you should either take filename from client, and then use reguest get to download that file, instead of writing the file again :)